# Wrong order of intervals in Pareto chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have some table with 2 columns of data. First one is project id, other is Time To Market in days (finish date minus start date). Smth like:

| Id | TTM |
| --- | --- |
| ID-1 | 23 |
| ID-2 | 11 |
| ID-3 | 167 |
| ID-4 | 2 |
| ID-5 | 40 |

I'm trying to make Pareto chart. I have selected this data (two ranges) and create a diagram with type "Pareto". Excel automatically found the correct columns for X and Y Axis, but used not appropriate intervals for X Axis. I have set interval equal to 15 and then it's almost fine... Almost. I do not know why, but it's ordered the columns on X Axis in the wrong order. It's moved zero values to the end instead of correct order for numbers.

E.g. it's rendering char with intervals: ... (75, 90], (150, 65], (165, 180], **(90, 105], (105, 120]**, etc.
[image]

I have tried to sort the data or find some settings but not succeeded.

I want to get X Axis in the next order: ... (75, 90], (90, 105], (105, 120], ..., (150, 65], (165, 180]. How can i do that?

Comment: A Pareto chart plots the bars from tallest to shortest, regardless of any numerical values you may enter. A Histogram plots bars according to values along the X axis, the bins. It sounds like you want a Histogram.

Comment: @LbISS, please refer to "[Create a Pareto chart](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pareto-chart-a1512496-6dba-4743-9ab1-df5012972856)", the lengths of the bars represent frequency or cost (time or money), and are arranged with longest bars on the left and the shortest to the right.

Comment: The data you posted (ID-1, ID-2, etc.) doesn't match the chart (0-15, 15-30, etc.), but whatever. A Pareto chart sorts by the number of incidences, tallest to shortest. If you want to keep your "numerical" values in order, make a regular column chart, which will make something more like a histogram.

Answer (score 0):

A pareto chart typically uses a text axis, i.e. a category axis, not a numeric axis, and it sorts the  data values from largest category to smallest category.

I pasted your data into Excel, selected it and with two clicks had this pareto chart:

[image]

When you click the chart, the data it uses will be highlighted. Make sure that the desired text cells are selected for the X axis. You can edit the range in the Chart Source dialog.

[image]

You can change the axis from a category to a numeric axis, but that doesn't make sense for a pareto chart, since by definition it wants to sort the data by category. This cannot be done if the axis is set to numeric.

You may want to format the axis and set it back to "By Category"

[image]

Comment: So there is no setting for axis sorting, right? 

The only way to get correct sorting is to make aggregate table with required sorting and use plain histogram withour pareto chart?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. A pareto chart is sorted. If you want to do a different sort on the axis, it is not a pareto chart. So, you may be using the wrong chart for what you want to achieve. As Jon Peltier said in his comment.